# what exactly is the point of javascript prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

i get absolutely the same results whether i use "this.value=1;" inside the constructor function or just put property value inside prototype of function constructor -  "MyClass.prototype.value =1;"

```
function MyClass() {
 //this.value=1;
}
MyClass.prototype.value =1;


var a = new MyClass();
document.write(a.value + "<br>");
a.value=13;
document.write(a.value + "<br>");

var b = new MyClass();
document.write(b.value);
```

result is :

1

13

1

since last value is 1, obviously every object (a,b) get it's own copy of value inside it's own memory block
so what exactly is the use of prototype values if they are not shared between objects?

Comment: Is it just me, or is this question asked way too many times? D:

Answer (score 6):

Your test is specious. Prototype values *are* shared between values, but in writing `a.value = 13`, you've [shadowed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the `MyClass.prototype.value` property on `a`. Try this on for size:

```
function MyClass() {}
MyClass.prototype.value = 1;

var a = new MyClass();
document.write(a.value + "<br>");
a.__proto__.value=13;
document.write(a.value + "<br>");

var b = new MyClass();
document.write(b.value);
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/e3Zhf/))

Object property lookups travel up the prototype chain until either the prototype is null, or a property with the specified name is found. In your original test `a.value = 13` causes lookups on `a.value` to end with `a` – since there is a property called `value` on that object – before ever reaching the prototype.

More reading:

- [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)
- [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Comment: a.prototype.value=13; doesn't work - "a.prototype is undefined"

Answer (score 2):

> *"I get absolutely the same results"*

Only because you don't yet know how to interpret your test results.

All instances share the properties from the prototype, but instances can have instance properties with the same names as those of the prototype.

So when you say `a.value = 13` you are creating a property on the `a` instance but the prototype `value` property is still `1`.

If you instead said `MyClass.prototype.value = 13` you'd see that both `a.value` and `b.value` report `13` even if you change the prototype's `value` *after* creating `a` and `b`.